# Which one is best for performance in jquery select class names vs id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have along div's for accordion menu with each has id's likes

```
<div id='sampe_1' class='sample'></div>
<div id='sampe_2' class='sample'></div>
<div id='sampe_3' class='sample'></div>

<div id='sampe_100' class='sample'></div>
```

For expand and collapse 
To find all div's i am using below two methods

`$("div[id^='sample_']");` 
I got all 100 div no i loop 100 times and click event

or

Direct click event with class name

```
$('.sample').on('click');
```

In above both which one best or any better  process

Comment: you can also do `$("div[id^='supplier_']").on('click')` if you want... but I will opt for the class if that is unique

Comment: @ Arun P Johny  what if click event for child elements under that div like $('.sample samplechild')

Comment: The question is whether this code is run multiple times; if run only once,  whichever method you choose shouldn't matter so much (assuming the page isn't huge).

Comment: using the the class make more sense since you want to apply the event to a set of DOM nodes. 1) it's more readable, 2) better performance

Comment: @jack i'm using that for multiple times

Answer (score 1):

In this case `$('.sample').on('click');` would be faster because with the id's a RegEx has to be executed for every element while for the `class` every element is just collected for that class only. So there is no comparison happening when `binding` the `click` event to the `DOM element`.

Comment: It's possible that jQuery optimises the expression to use `getElementsByTagName()` and then filter them using a regular expression, so it doesn't necessarily inspect all elements.

Comment: @Jack: Selecting by a class only can certainly not be optimized by using a method that selects based on the tag name of an element …

Comment: @CBroe I didn't suggest that were the case.

Comment: @Jack ah, you meant that in regard to the original `div[id^='sample_']`, I see.